# Android ListView end scroll

Tags: android, android-listview

Is it possible to get triggered, if a `ListView` has ended scrolling?

I want to implement a check **after** the user scrolled the `ListView`. It would be to much checks, if I check this in

```
AbsListView.OnScrollListener.onScroll()
```

and it's not needed every pixel movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState){

if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
//stopped scrolling
}
}
```

Comment: And how do I check, if `ListView`.setSelectionFromTop() has ended? This doesn't set the ScrollState.

Comment: I just read the setSelectionFromTop method provided by Android, and it does not send any events it seems. It does request layout at the end

Comment: So, I have to do it in **onScroll**. Okay, but it was a great hint to use **onScrollStateChanged**.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)    {
     if((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) == totalItemCount) {
            //End Scroll
     }
}
```

**firstVisibleItem** - is the first item which is visible on the screen, 
**visibleItemCount** - count of visible items on the screen.

This should work.